# Use image as a hyperlink and to save a textbox input value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

In my website, I have a textbox which I'm using to ask the user for their name. Below I have 2 images, a cancel "button" which is just an image which has an  tag to take it back to the index, and a Go image which is linked to another HTML page where the input taken from the text box will be used to fill in a paragraph. This page is linked below:

[image]

I am fine with how the cancel image is functioning but is it possible for me to use the Go image to take me to my other HTML page as well as to store the data input into the "your name" text box?

```
<div class="name_input_box">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" id="name" required />
    <label for="name" class="label_name">
    </label>
</div>
```

my code for the input box^

```
 <a href="Add_page.html">
        <img src="assets/Go_button.png" img style="height:35%; width:35%;">
        </a>
```

My code for the "go" image^

I appreciate this might seem simple but I can't find any video tutorials on how to tackle this, many thanks to anyone who takes the time to help me on Easter Sunday :)

Comment: The question is: how do you want to persist/store the data? It has to be the form of a client-side storage, i.e. cookies, sessionStorage or localStorage.

Comment: I believe localStorage would be the best method for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either use localStorage or just have a form

```
<form action="Add_page.html">
  <div class="name_input_box">
    <label for="name" class="label_name"><input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" required /></label>
    <input type="image" src="assets/Go_button.png" img style="height:35%; width:35%;">
  </div>
</form>
```

and use the location.search to get the name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your code and got rid of my other code for the go button in a separate div and was given this: http://prntscr.com/rxr99x . The go button is taking the style.css from the Div for the input box. Any Idea how I can separate these? Thanks again.

Comment: Move the button outside the div? Post a complete example with CSS

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions well, I think this is what you are looking for. 
Local storage stores your data for your and you can get your data any time you need it. 
try this out linking this script to your html code and making reference to the right id's.

```
// get data from the input tag/local storage value
var input_data = document.getElementById('input_data').value

//local storage key
var key_name = 'UserName';

// paragraph to fill input  ..you can p tag for this  
var result_screen = document.getElementById('result_screen')

// image link / button
var goBtn = document.getElementById('goBtn');

goBtn.onclick = function () {

    // To check for empty input value 
    if (key_name && value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key_name, input_data);
        location.reload();
    }

}

// loop through the input value entered by users 

for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var key_name = localStorage.key_name(i);
    var input_data = localStorage.getItem(key_name);

    result_screen.innerHTML += `${key_name}: ${value}<br>`;
}
```